# jsf primefaces two datatables and two lists

Tags: hibernate, jsf, primefaces

I'm developing a project using jsf hibernate primefaces.
In my xhtml page there are two datatable.
When I click one of the rows in datatable, It shows the details in second datatable.
How can I make this happen ?
Thanks

InfoProcess.java:

```
here is my complete InfoProcess.java code 

package com.revir.process;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.revir.managed.bean.AddressBean;
import com.revir.managed.bean.OgrenimSureciBean;
import com.revir.domain.Adres;
import com.revir.domain.AdresDAO;
import com.revir.domain.Kisi;
import com.revir.domain.KisiDAO;
import com.revir.domain.Kisiadresi;
import com.revir.domain.Ogrenimsureci;
import com.revir.domain.OgrenimsureciDAO;
import com.revir.domain.Ulke;
import com.revir.process.KisiInfoProcess;

@ManagedBean(name = "userOS")
@SessionScoped
public class KisiInfoProcess implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(KisiInfoProcess.class);

    private List<OgrenimSureciBean> osList;

    private List<AddressBean> adresList;

    private OgrenimSureciBean selectedOS;

    private AddressBean selectedAdres;

    public OgrenimSureciBean getSelectedOS() {
        getSelectedAdres();
        return selectedOS;
    }

    public void setSelectedOS(OgrenimSureciBean selectedOS) {
        this.selectedOS = selectedOS;
    }

    public AddressBean getSelectedAdres() {
        return selectedAdres;
    }

    public void setSelectedAdres(AddressBean selectedAdres) {
        this.selectedAdres = selectedAdres;
    }

    public List<OgrenimSureciBean> getOsList() {
        OgrenimsureciDAO ogrenimsureciDAO = new OgrenimsureciDAO();

        List<OgrenimSureciBean> osList = new ArrayList<OgrenimSureciBean>();

        for (Iterator i = ogrenimsureciDAO.findByMezunOgrenciler((short) 8)
                .iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            Ogrenimsureci og = (Ogrenimsureci) i.next();
            OgrenimSureciBean osBean = new OgrenimSureciBean();

            osBean.setBolum(og.getBolum());
            osBean.setAd(og.getKisiByKisiid().getAd());
            osBean.setSoyad(og.getKisiByKisiid().getSoyad());
            osBean.setAltbirim(og.getAltbirim());
            osBean.setOgrencino(og.getOgrencino());
            osBean.setKisiid(og.getKisiByKisiid().getKisiid());
            osBean.setOgrencidurum(og.getOgrencidurum());

            osList.add(osBean);
            System.out.println("osBean : " + osBean.toString());

        }
        return osList;
    }

    public void setOsList(List<OgrenimSureciBean> osList) {
        this.osList = osList;
    }

    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {

        System.out.println("On Row Select Metodu çalıştı");

            try {
                getAdresList();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    }

    public List<AddressBean> getAdresList() throws Exception {

        log.debug("PersonalInfoProcess - getAddressInfo - Start");
        List<AddressBean> adresList = new ArrayList<AddressBean>();

        KisiDAO kisiDAO = new KisiDAO();
        AdresDAO adresDAO = new AdresDAO();

        Long kisiid = getSelectedOS().getKisiid();
        System.out.println("kisiid :" + kisiid);
        Kisi kisi = kisiDAO.findById(kisiid);

        for (Iterator i = kisi.getKisiadresis().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

            Kisiadresi kisiAdresi = (Kisiadresi) i.next();
            System.out.println("i :" + i);
            Adres tmpAdres = adresDAO.findById(kisiAdresi.getId().getAdresid());

            if (tmpAdres != null) {
                AddressBean address = new AddressBean(kisiid);

                if (tmpAdres.getAdresturu() == null) {
                    address.setAddressType(null);
                } else {
                    address.setAddressType(tmpAdres.getAdresturu().getAd());
                }

                address.setAddress(tmpAdres.getAdres());

                if (tmpAdres.getIl() == null) {
                    address.setCity(null);
                } else {
                    address.setCity(tmpAdres.getIl().getAd());
                }

                if (tmpAdres.getUlke() == null) {
                    address.setCountry(null);
                } else {
                    address.setCountry(tmpAdres.getUlke().getAd());
                }

                adresList.add(address);

                System.out.println("adres" + address);
                System.out.println("adreslist" + adresList);
            }

            log.debug("PersonalInfoProcess - getAddressInfo - End / Returning");
        }
        return adresList;
    }

    public void setAdresList(List<AddressBean> adresList) {
        this.adresList = adresList;
    }

}
```

index.xhtml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <f:view>
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:dataTable id="users" var="user" value="#{userOS.osList}"
                paginator="true" rows="10" rowKey="#{user.kisiid}"
                selection="#{userOS.selectedOS}" selectionMode="single">
                <f:facet name="header">  
                                        Kullanıcı detaylarını görmek için view butonuna tıklayınız
                                        </f:facet>
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{userOS.onRowSelect}" update=":form:display"
                    oncomplete="userDialog" />

                <p:column headerText="Student No" sortBy="ogrencino"
                    filterBy="ogrencino" id="ogrencino">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.ogrencino}" />
                    <f:param name="kid" value="#{userOS.osList.rowIndex}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="ad" filterBy="ad" id="ad">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.ad}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Surname" sortBy="soyad" filterBy="soyad"
                    id="soyad">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.soyad}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Faculty" sortBy="altbirim.ad"
                    filterBy="altbirim.ad" id="altbirim">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.altbirim.ad}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Department" sortBy="bolum.ad"
                    filterBy="bolum.ad" id="bolum">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.bolum.ad}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Status" sortBy="ogrencidurum.ad"
                    filterBy="ogrencidurum.ad" id="ogrencidurum">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.ogrencidurum.ad}" />
                </p:column>

                <f:facet name="footer">
                </f:facet>
            </p:dataTable>

            <p:panel id="dialog" header="User Detail" widgetVar="userDialog">

                <h:panelGrid id="panelgrid" columns="2" cellpadding="4">
                    <p:dataTable id="display" var="adres" value="#{userOS.adresList}">
                        <p:column headerText="Adres Tipi">
                            <h:outputText value="#{adres.addressType}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Adres">
                            <h:outputText value="#{adres.address}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="İl">
                            <h:outputText value="#{adres.city}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Ülke">
                            <h:outputText value="#{adres.country}" />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </h:panelGrid>

            </p:panel>


        </h:form>
    </f:view>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an OS can have various addresses, right? The second datatable should not have   `{userOS.selectedOS}`as its value. Instead, it should point to a list of addresses that should be populated in your `onRowSelect()`method. Keep in mind that a datatable needs a value that is an object that is a collection of some sort in order to work. That is not the case with `{userOS.selectedOS}`.

Here's what I'd do:

1. Add a list of addresses to your bean and populate that list in your `onRowSelect()` method
2. Create a getter for that list
3. Make your second datatable point to that list;
4. Remove `oncomplete="userDialog"`from your `p:ajax` tag (it will probably give you a javascript error unless you have a `p:remoteCommand` with that name somewhere)
5. Although you should be able to update a datatable directly from `p:ajax`, I've had problems with that in the past so I normally just wrap a mine in a panel group and update the panel group instead. Give that I try if you're having issues.

About your OS list (first datatable): never use getters to perform complex operations (like accessing the database). Those getters get executed many times during the JSF lifecycle and you don't want to repeat a bunch of queries to the database, right? Print something to the console in the beginning of the method `getOsList()` or put a breakpoint there if you don't believe me. You should declare a list in your bean and populate that list when appropriate. If you're using session scoped beans, you need to populate the list every time you navigate to that page. If you're using view/request scoped beans, the bean constructor would be a good place to populate the list.

**EDIT**:

Add this to the form tag in your xhtml:

```
...
<h:form prependId="false">
        <f:metadata>
            <f:event type="preRenderView"
                listener="#{userOS.populateOsList}" />
        </f:metadata>
...
```

This will populate the OS list when you load the page. It's important to do this here since your bean is session scoped and loading the list in the constructor could introduce some problems.

I refactored your bean code. Try this:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "userOS")
@SessionScoped
public class KisiInfoProcess implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(KisiInfoProcess.class);
    private List<OgrenimSureciBean> osList;
    private List<AddressBean> adresList;
    private OgrenimSureciBean selectedOS;
    private AddressBean selectedAdres;

    public OgrenimSureciBean getSelectedOS() {
        return selectedOS;
    }
    public void setSelectedOS(OgrenimSureciBean selectedOS) {
        this.selectedOS = selectedOS;
    }
    public AddressBean getSelectedAdres() {
        return selectedAdres;
    }
    public void setSelectedAdres(AddressBean selectedAdres) {
        this.selectedAdres = selectedAdres;
    }

    public void setOsList(List<OgrenimSureciBean> osList) {
        this.osList = osList;
    }

    public List<OgrenimSureciBean> getOsList(){
        return this.osList;
    }

    public void setAdresList(List<AddressBean> adresList) {
        this.adresList = adresList;
    }

    public List<AdressBean> getAdresList(){
        return this.adresList;
    }

    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        try {
            populateAddresList((OgrenimSureciBean) event.getObject());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void populateOsList() {
        OgrenimsureciDAO ogrenimsureciDAO = new OgrenimsureciDAO();

        osList = new ArrayList<OgrenimSureciBean>();

        for (Iterator i = ogrenimsureciDAO.findByMezunOgrenciler((short) 8)
                .iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            Ogrenimsureci og = (Ogrenimsureci) i.next();
            OgrenimSureciBean osBean = new OgrenimSureciBean();

            osBean.setBolum(og.getBolum());
            osBean.setAd(og.getKisiByKisiid().getAd());
            osBean.setSoyad(og.getKisiByKisiid().getSoyad());
            osBean.setAltbirim(og.getAltbirim());
            osBean.setOgrencino(og.getOgrencino());
            osBean.setKisiid(og.getKisiByKisiid().getKisiid());
            osBean.setOgrencidurum(og.getOgrencidurum());

            osList.add(osBean);
            System.out.println("osBean : " + osBean.toString());

        }
        return osList;
    }

    public void populateAddresList(OgrenimSureciBean selected) throws Exception {

        log.debug("PersonalInfoProcess - getAddressInfo - Start");
        adresList = new ArrayList<AddressBean>();

        KisiDAO kisiDAO = new KisiDAO();
        AdresDAO adresDAO = new AdresDAO();

        Long kisiid = selected.getKisiid();
        System.out.println("kisiid :" + kisiid);
        Kisi kisi = kisiDAO.findById(kisiid);

        for (Iterator i = kisi.getKisiadresis().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

            Kisiadresi kisiAdresi = (Kisiadresi) i.next();
            System.out.println("i :" + i);
            Adres tmpAdres = adresDAO.findById(kisiAdresi.getId().getAdresid());

            if (tmpAdres != null) {
                AddressBean address = new AddressBean(kisiid);

                if (tmpAdres.getAdresturu() == null) {
                    address.setAddressType(null);
                } else {
                    address.setAddressType(tmpAdres.getAdresturu().getAd());
                }

                address.setAddress(tmpAdres.getAdres());

                if (tmpAdres.getIl() == null) {
                    address.setCity(null);
                } else {
                    address.setCity(tmpAdres.getIl().getAd());
                }

                if (tmpAdres.getUlke() == null) {
                    address.setCountry(null);
                } else {
                    address.setCountry(tmpAdres.getUlke().getAd());
                }

                adresList.add(address);

                System.out.println("adres" + address);
                System.out.println("adreslist" + adresList);
            }

            log.debug("PersonalInfoProcess - getAddressInfo - End / Returning");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the populate methods do not return a list; they use the list declared on the bean itself. Those are the lists you'll point your page to.

Comment: I changed selectedUser to adresList now I'm getting this error: javax.el.ELException: /index2.xhtml @54,72 value="#{userOS.adresList}": Error reading 'adresList' on type com.revir.process.InfoProcess Also I added my whole InfoProcess.java code

Comment: Can you please show your list to do on my code, I'll be glad if you make those changes in my code

Comment: Your getAdresList method throws an exception. I'm pretty sure JSF doesn't like that. Create a regular getter for your address list that just returns the list. Populate the list in another somewhere else, preferably with another name.

Comment: Unfortunately you will have to figure it out yourself as I also have a job ;)

Comment: So I have to create adresList with another name and just return the the list if I understand right